# I need a multi channel cappable DAW for Raspberry pi

Tags: audio, software-recommendation, midi, software

I invented a musical MIDI instrument, and I want  to integrate it into a single portable unit for display purposes. I have tried some synth software, but haven't found anything that works with a PI, and does multi channel MIDI input. The simpler the better, all I really need to be able to do is process multi channel usb MIDI input.

Comment: the first thing that springs to mind is `lmms` - not sure if it's capable of what you want it to do though